# Replacing Linux Distro with another in dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, grub, replace, distributions

I'm using a dual system Debian/Win10, and I'm trying to replace my Debian with Fedora, so I booted into Windows then deleted the Debian partition, used Diskpart to list partitions and then `rd debian /S` to delete Debian from UEFI and avoid any grub issues while booting, it worked fine, no grub anymore and windows boots successfully. The issue is that when I try to boot from a Fedora live USB, I got a black screen with this message: "Minimal BASH like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.". Any ideas why do I get this message and how can I proceed to the Fedora installation?

I searched for the message but all I got was post-boot steps, like after booting from the live USB do x, but I can't even boot from the USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It showed up that it was a USB issue, I deleted the USB volume from windows disk management, removed the USB and inserted it again and updated rufus to its last version and it worked fine